# Provider for Single View Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm working with the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package for Flutter. What I want to accomplish is to have a simple provider just for one view or page. So I tried the following in my widget:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyModel>(
      create: (_) => MyModel(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Screen 1',
          ),
        ),
        body: _buildBody(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

but when I try to access the provider using a `Provider.of<MyModel>(context, listen: false).value` in my `_buildBody()` method I get the error:

> Could not find the correct Provider above this MyPageWidget

When I move the declaration of the provider to where I declare my App above this Widget it works. Unfortunately this makes the provider public for all of my views to access which is not what I want. How can I make a provider that just can be accessed within that one view or widget. Thanks for any help.

---

Note: I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60022197/9609442) but I'm still getting the same result.

**Edit**: I could use a `Consumer` at the top of my widget tree, but doesn't that cause the page to rebuild too much if my whole widget tree is in the `Consumer`. Further, what if I need to use `Provider.of(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution to this that doesn't require rebuilding the whole widget tree when a change happens like @GJJ2019 answer. When I declare the route, for example:

```dart
'/': (context) => MyScreen();
```

I wrap `MyScreen` with the `ChangeNotifierProvider` for example:

```dart
'/': (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider<MyModel>(
  create: (_) => MyModel(),
  child: MyScreen()),
```

So instead of declaring the provider in the widget/screen that it was being used, declare the provider where you declare the route.

Comment: So, I understand, we should put Providers at the top of the app, it means placing them at Main.dart right?

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the scaffold with consumer

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyModel>(
  create: (_) => MyModel(),
  child: Consumer(
    builder: (context, MyModel model, _) => Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Screen 1',
        ),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Now u can access my model directly by passing it through the method

Comment: This seems like a round-a-bout way of accomplishing this because now the whole widget tree gets rebuilt every time there is a change and I have to pass `model` into every function. Is what I'm trying to accomplish in provider an anti-pattern, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does the whole widget tree get rebuilt every time `notifyListeners()` is called when everything is wrapped by the `Consumer`?

Comment: but if i want to call some function from a provider in initState() or didChangedependencies() , this can't be possible using the above code.