# Another exception was thrown: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AppData> above this History Widget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-provider, flutter-listview

am facing this problem for a while now and i've no flutter community in my country so am forced to post online if i get any help and i will be glad if i found one cuz am in the deployment face of this app and it is the only thing stopping from publishing and getting paid so please guys i need help

[![`am getting this error for a week now`][1]][1]

> **this is my home**

```
import 'package:connection_status_bar/connection_status_bar.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:taxi/Driver/HomeScreen.dart';
import 'package:taxi/Driver/carInfo..dart';
import 'package:taxi/Driver/loginPage.dart';
import 'package:taxi/config.dart';
import 'package:taxi/riders/Screens/HomeScreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:taxi/riders/Screens/PhoneAuthInfo.dart';
import 'package:taxi/riders/Screens/Profile.dart';
import 'package:taxi/riders/Screens/historyScreen.dart';
import 'package:taxi/riders/Screens/landingPage.dart';
import 'package:taxi/riders/Screens/loginPage.dart';
import 'package:taxi/riders/Screens/signUp.dart';
import 'package:taxi/riders/data/Data.dart';
import 'package:taxi/Driver/signUp.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  currentfirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
 ChangeNotifierProvider(
                create: (context) => AppData(),)
    ],
      child: EasyLocalization(

      child: MyApp(),
      path: "images/resources",
      saveLocale: true,
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('am', 'ET'),
        Locale('en', 'CA'),
        Locale('en', 'US')
      ],
      fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
    ),
  )
  );
}

DatabaseReference userRef =
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users");
DatabaseReference driverRef =
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("drivers");

DatabaseReference newRequestsRef =
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Ride Request");
DatabaseReference rideRequestRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .child("drivers")
    .child(currentfirebaseUser.uid)
    .child("newRide");

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Goosh',
      theme: ThemeData(
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
        fontFamily: "Font regular",
        primaryColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      builder: (context, _) => Stack(children: [
      
           MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Goosh',
            theme: ThemeData(
              cursorColor: Color(0xff5f86ba),
              fontFamily: "Font regular",
              primaryColor: Color(0xff5f86ba),
            ),
            localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,

            supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
            locale: context.locale,
            initialRoute: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null
                ? PhoneAuth.idScreen
                : HomeScreen.idScreen,
            // initialRoute:  Login.idScreen,
            routes: {
              PhoneAuth.idScreen: (context) => PhoneAuth(),
              Login.idScreen: (context) => Login(),
              SignUp.idScreen: (context) => SignUp(),
              HomeScreen.idScreen: (context) => HomeScreen(),
              DriverSignUp.idScreen: (context) => DriverSignUp(),
              DriverLogin.idScreen: (context) => DriverLogin(),
              CarInfo.idScreen: (context) => CarInfo(),
              DriverMainScreen.idScreen: (context) => DriverMainScreen(),
              HistoryScreen.idScreen: (route) => HistoryScreen(),
              PhoneAuthInfo.idScreen: (context) => PhoneAuthInfo(),
              ProfilePage.idScreen: (context) => ProfilePage()
            },
          ),
       
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: ConnectionStatusBar(
              lookUpAddress: 'google.com',
              height: 32,
              animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
              title: Material(
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                child: Text(
                  'Please check your internet connection',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                ),
              )),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

> **and this is how i navigate to this page**

```
 ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.local_taxi_outlined),
        title: Text("My Gooshs".tr().toString()),
        onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HistoryScreen()));
        },
     ),
```

> **and this is my history screen code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:taxi/riders/data/data.dart';
import 'package:taxi/riders/widget/historyItem.dart';

class HistoryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String idScreen = "HistoryScreen";

  @override
  _HistoryScreenState createState() => _HistoryScreenState();
}

class _HistoryScreenState extends State<HistoryScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("History"),
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_left),
          ),
        ),
        body: History());
  }
}

class History extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return HistoryItem(
          history: Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
              .tripHistoryDataList[index],
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(
        height: 2.0,
        thickness: 2.0,
      ),
      itemCount: Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).tripHistoryDataList.length,
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
    );
  }
}
```

> **and this is my single history item**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:taxi/riders/assistance/DriverAssistMethod.dart';
import 'package:taxi/riders/model/History.dart';

class HistoryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final History history;
  HistoryItem({this.history});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  'images/pickicon.png',
                  height: 16.0,
                  width: 16.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 18.0),
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                        child: Text(history.pickUp,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)))),
                Text(
                  '${history.fares}',
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Font bold', fontSize: 16.0),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8.0,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                'images/desticon.png',
                height: 16.0,
                width: 16.0,
              ),
              Text(history.dropOff,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0))
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15.0,
          ),
          Text(
            DriverAssistantMethods.formatTripDate(history.createdAt),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> **and this is my provider data**

```
import 'package:taxi/riders/model/History.dart';
import 'package:taxi/riders/model/adress.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppData extends ChangeNotifier{

  Address pickupLocation, dropOffLocation;

  int countTrips = 0;
  List<String> tripHistoryKeys = [];
  List<History> tripHistoryDataList = [];


  void updatePickUpLocationAddress(Address pickUpAddress)
  {
    pickupLocation = pickUpAddress;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updatedropOffLocationAddress(Address dropOffAddress)
  {
    dropOffLocation = dropOffAddress;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateTripsCounter(int tripCounter){
    countTrips = tripCounter;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void updateTripKeys(List<String> newKeys){
    tripHistoryKeys = newKeys;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void updateTripData(History eachhistory){
    tripHistoryDataList.add(eachhistory);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  

}
```

> **and this is how i fetch data from the realtime database**

```
static void retrieveHistory(context) {
   
    //retrieve history and Trip History
    newRequestsRef
        .orderByChild("rider_name")
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
        //update total number of trip to provider
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> keys = dataSnapshot.value;
        int tripCounter = keys.length;
        Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
            .updateTripsCounter(tripCounter);
        //update trip keys of trip to provider
        List<String> tripHistoryKeys = [];
        keys.forEach((key, value) {
          tripHistoryKeys.add(key);
        });
        Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
            .updateTripKeys(tripHistoryKeys);
        obtainTripRequestHistoryData(context);
      }
    });
  }

  static void obtainTripRequestHistoryData(context) {
    var keys = Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).tripHistoryKeys;
    for (String key in keys) {
      newRequestsRef.child(key).once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
          newRequestsRef
              .child(key)
              .child("rider_name")
              .once()
              .then((DataSnapshot dsnap) {
            String name = dsnap.value.toString();  
            if (name == userCurrentInfo.name) {
              var history = History.fromSnapshot(dataSnapshot);
              Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).updateTripData(history);
            }
          
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRBAD.jpg
```

Comment: First, the image link to your error message is broken. Second, don't post an image link to the error message, just copy and paste the error message.

Comment: ok men got it, i just did that for better clarification

Answer (score 0):

I think main() is the bug, should

```
void main() {
  var colorProvider = ColorProvider();
  var counterProvider = CounterProvider();
  Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;

  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: colorProvider),
      ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: counterProvider),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

you can look my demo:  https://github.com/pheromone/Flutter_learn_demo/tree/master/%E5%85%B6%E4%BB%96/state%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86/provider_demo4.x