# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<CartModel> above this Consumer<CartModel> Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this error while running the app. I not so advanced in flutter yet. Trying to find solutions. Can u guys help me please?
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Consumer Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Consumer is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
  ```

My code here below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CartModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  // list of items on sale
  final List _shopItems = const [
    // [ itemName, itemPrice, imagePath, color ]
    ["Avocado", "4.00", "lib/images/avocado.png", Colors.green],
    ["Banana", "2.50", "lib/images/banana.png", Colors.yellow],
    ["Chicken", "12.80", "lib/images/chicken.png", Colors.brown],
    ["Water", "1.00", "lib/images/water.png", Colors.blue],
  ];

  // list of cart items
  final List _cartItems = [];

  get cartItems => _cartItems;

  get shopItems => _shopItems;

  // add item to cart
  void addItemToCart(int index) {
    _cartItems.add(_shopItems[index]);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // remove item from cart
  void removeItemFromCart(int index) {
    _cartItems.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // calculate total price
  String calculateTotal() {
    double totalPrice = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
      totalPrice += double.parse(cartItems[i][1]);
    }
    return totalPrice.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }
}
```

//another page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'cart_model.dart';


class CartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CartPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle:true,
        title: const Text("My Cart",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 24,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),

        backgroundColor: Colors.green[600],
        elevation: 0,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.grey[800],
        ),
      ),
      body: Consumer<CartModel>(
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              // Let's order fresh items for you


              // list view of cart
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: value.cartItems.length,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.grey[200],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: Image.asset(
                              value.cartItems[index][2],
                              height: 36,
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              value.cartItems[index][0],
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(
                              "\$" + value.cartItems[index][1],
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                            trailing: IconButton(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                              onPressed: () =>
                                  Provider.of<CartModel>(context, listen: false)
                                      .removeItemFromCart(index),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              // total amount + pay now

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Total Price',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[200]),
                          ),

                          const SizedBox(height: 8),
                          // total price
                          Text(
                            '\$${value.calculateTotal()}',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),

                      // pay now
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.green.shade200),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                        child: Row(
                          children: const [
                            Text(
                              'Pay Now',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                              size: 16,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: before using the provider, you need to define it on top of widget tree.   common practice is define on main.dart. so your provider guarantee on top all of the widget tree

Comment: i dont know how to expalin it in simple way. but you can see this example https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifierprovider

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find the correct Provider - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57539094/could-not-find-the-correct-provider-flutter)